# Azure AD authentication with Institutional and Microsoft accounts

Tags: adal

I have a custom MVC WebApplication with WebApi-service that require authentication/authorization. I followed the example on GitHub [WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIDConnect-DotNet](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIDConnect-DotNet). While developing I created a new test directory on my personal Azure subscription and everything worked perfectly fine. I could add institutional accounts (like jon@mytenantname.onmicrosoft.com) and existing Microsoft accounts (jon@hotmail.com) and assign them to different groups.
When a user typed in a liveID email address on the login page and moved the cursor to the password textbox, he was redirected to a Microsoft account login page.

Now I published the application to our production web server and want to connect the applications to a synchronized Azure Active Directory. It works with all institutional (work-) accounts. But when I add a Microsoft account, and try to login with those credentials, the redirection does not work anymore. The login page displays in red:

> We don't recognize this user ID or password
>   Make sure you typed the user ID assigned to you by your organization. It usually looks like someone@example.com or someone@example.onmicrosoft.com. And check to make sure you typed the correct password.

What am I missing? Is it possible to use synchronized institutional and personal Microsoft accounts together in one directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My team owns the sign-in UX for Azure AD. 
The fact that the AAD login page recognizes domains like outlook.com and redirects users to the Microsoft account (Live ID) login page is a happenstance. It doesn’t work for all consumer domains, and it must not be relied on to enable MSA sign in to your apps. If you want to support sign in for Azure AD and MSA users, you need to show separate sign-in buttons in your app. We're looking at how we can make this experience better in the longer term.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Ariel, has there been any progress on this? We would like to use ADAL with v1 endpoint as v2 does not support the scopes we need for Exchange Online. I gather ADAL does not work with MSAs but why not?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using openid connect like in the sample, and you are not using the /common endpoint,there should be no difference between the two scenarios.
I assume you are an admin in your prod directory as well? Did you provision the Microsoft accounts in your prod directory in the exact same way as you did in your test directory?

Comment: I created a new example from scratch and published it [here](https://waad.azurewebsites.net/). Then I created two new users in the directory. One "in your organization" and one "with an existing Microsoft account". Both in the Azure portal site. The first can sign in, the second not :-(

Comment: This should work with openid connect- the only other thing that comes to mind is if you are asking for permissions that work only for administrators. Can you try to ensure that both users have exactly the same roles, then go through the sample again?

Comment: The institutional account that works is only in the organizational role "User". The Microsoft account that doesn't work is assigned to the "Global Administrator" role.

Comment: Wow, the plot is thickening. Are you positive you don't use the login.windows.net/common endpoint?

Comment: Thanks for your patience. How could I change the endpoint URI? My application is a 1:1 clone from the GitHub example and I only changed the values in web.config. Nothing else. Now I added the Microsoft account of a colleague, he types his email on the login page, hits TAB and is redirected. With my two Microsoft accounts not. What can be wrong with them. Can I post the addresses here?

Comment: if you just cloned, then your endpoint should be good. Another rthing that might go wrong is if the microsoft accounts are not classic *Hotmail.com, *live.com, etc but they are instead based on vanity domains (eg *mydomain.com) and are also used for a directory, in which case they won't work here. If you want to discuss in more details feel free to hit me via http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/contact/