# Cant use my microsoft account to log into my test app using active directory

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, adfs, azure-active-directory

I have recently been following samples such as  https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet from the msdn code sample page - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn646737.aspx

The samples themselves work and I am always able to login using the custom domain that I created in my azure something@something.onmicrosoft.com. I also added a few people myself included using our custom domain Microsoft accounts which we use for all of our msdn logins as users but so far have not been able to login as these accounts using the "organizational or school account" login page .

The error we get is:

We don't recognize this user ID or password Make sure you typed the user ID assigned to you by your organization. It usually looks like someone@example.comor someone@example.onmicrosoft.com. And check to make sure you typed the correct password.

I have done some googling trying to see if anyone is able to login like this but so far other people have the same issues as me:  [Azure AD authentication with Institutional and Microsoft accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797846/azure-ad-authentication-with-institutional-and-microsoft-accounts) and  https://serverfault.com/questions/657848/user-with-an-existing-microsoft-account-cannot-access-app-using-azure-ad-sso

The github links that I pointed to even say in them that "This sample will not work with a Microsoft account".

However if I type something@live.com in the user name I get redirected to a Microsoft live login page where I can enter my Microsoft msdn account which I added to the users for the application and that works and lets me login to my app.

So I guess my question is why can't I just use Microsoft account to login with the default page that I get - the one that says "Sign in with your work or school account" - could I have some background on this why this isn't working? Is there a way that I can make the Microsoft live login page be the page that comes up with somebody tries to go to my app instead of the azure AD page?

We are doing a proof of concept to start transitioning our company apps into the cloud and getting azure AD working properly is the first step - Any help and info will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

krilovich, Azure AD login page does very basic disambiguation between Organizational and Live accounts and fails when the Live account doesn't look like the typical ones (@outlook.com/@hotmail.com etc.). We plan to improve this experience. However currently the only option is to show two login buttons in your app, one for "Work or School Account" which will send the authorize request that you're sending now and another for "Microsoft Account". The authorize request for Microsoft Account must add &domain_hint=live.com QS parameter. This will take the user directly to the Microsoft Account sign-in page.

Try this:
`https://login.windows.net/dushyantgill.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code%20id_token&client_id=112e0117-ef3d-44c4-a367-5b4bef313d8f&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.authnauthz.com%2Foauth%2Finboundauthenticationresponse&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net%2F&scope=profile%20email%20openid&nonce=c69605cd-a01c-4039-bb4a-61168eaf1d6a&response_mode=form_post&domain_hint=live.com`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the workaround!! Kinda unfortunate that a workaround like this is needed in the first place.. if azure AD gives me an option to add a Microsoft user of any type then i should be able to login as that user without having to do anything extra..

Answer (score 1):

There have been some improvements to Azure AD recently.

> In the past, an app developer who wanted to support both Microsoft accounts and Azure Active Directory was required to integrate with two separate systems. **With the v2.0 app model, you can now sign users in with both types of accounts.** One simple integration allows you to reach an audience that spans millions of users with both personal and work/school accounts.

[Read more here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview/)